# Xdebug in PhpStorm doesn't show local variables

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I trying install Xdebug on PhpStorm + OpenServer. Everywhere php v7.2. I tried several times to install different version of Xdebug.
There are my settings:

[image: Php.ini]

[image: Php.info]

[image: Validate debug Configuration]

Also have Xdebug helper in Chrome, but variables still doesn't display.

[image: No variables]

If I enable break at first line flag, phpstorm show me this, but if I press "step into" it disappears.
[image: magic variables]

Comment: Are you sure you're connecting back? How did you get the screen above? Make sure you're listening for xdebug connections (You can check this under the run menu item in the top bar of PHPStorm) I see no name for what you're debugging which makes me think your debugger isn't actually attached to anything.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that connection listening is enable (icon with phone is green).Where should be name? In frames?

Comment: Must be some path mapping issue... Any symbolic links used or stuff like that? Need details. Show your xdebug log for such session. What file you are trying to debug (the full path). Show your `PHP | Server` entry for this project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with console application. Try insert somewhere before function you watching:

```
ini_set('xdebug.collect_vars', 1)
```

Or execute it in evaluation window.